# pydot error in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm trying to run some TensorFlow code in my machine

This is my code:

````
```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

iris = load_iris()
test_idx = [0, 50, 100]

#training data
train_target = np.delete(iris.target, test_idx)
train_data = np.delete(iris.data, test_idx, axis=0)

#testing data
test_target = iris.target[test_idx]
test_data = iris.data[test_idx]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(train_data, train_target)

print test_target
print clf.predict(test_data)


from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
dot_data = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,
                         feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                         class_names=iris.target_names,
                         filled=True, rounded=True,
                         special_characters=True)
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png())```
````

and the output is:

`[0 1 2]
[0 1 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
NameError: name 'pydot' is not defined`

How I can fix this error? I tried to install pydot, but nothing fixed.

Comment: maybe `import pydot` ? ...

Comment: the output is that: `/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydot2-1.0.32-py2.7.egg/pydot.py", line 220, in graph_from_dot_data`